# Combining and sorting two different active record collections using an Id column and sort column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I have two different tables, which if time was taken could be made more similar or even combined but for convenience sake they are currently different. They both have an id column and a start_date column which is of type datetime.

I'm trying to think of a way that's not extremely convoluted or without using custom sql to get and sort the result into one sorted array using the start_date column.

Can anyone think of a quick way to do it? The tables have no active record relation at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the **simplest** way to do this would be

```
@objects = Duck.all + Quack.all



# Oldest first
@objects.sort! { |a, b| a.start_date <=> b.start_date }    
# Newest first
@objects.sort! { |a, b| b.start_date <=> a.start_date }
```

Comment: How do I add them into one array?  
`arr1 = Table1.all  
arr2 = Table2.all  
@arr = arr1 << arr2`

Comment: Cool. Yeah the great thing about Ruby is that you are not limited in the way of design patterns